# Material-UI Tooltip requires deletion of child title prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the Material-UI Tooltip component on a component which already has the title property. I must use the child with the title prop. Is there any way I can use the Material-UI tooltip, or do I need to find another?

```
<Tooltip title='Disabled' aria-label='disabled button'>
  <RequiredImportedButton title={this._getTitleMessage()} />
</Tooltip>
```

Material-UI throws this error:

> index.js:2178 Warning: Material-UI: you have provided a `title` property to the child of `<Tooltip />`.
>   Remove this title property `Delete` or the Tooltip component.

Thanks for any help you may have.

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a little more? What is the text returned by `this._getTitleMessage()`? Why would the button have a title with different text than the tooltip?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go with the simple approach: wrap the child component in a `div`.

```
<Tooltip title='Disabled' aria-label='disabled button'>
  <div>
    <RequiredImportedButton title={this._getTitleMessage()} />
  </div>
</Tooltip>
```

UPDATE:

Another answer suggested the use of a fragment instead of a `div`, as `div`s can cause unintended styling changes, but there was confusion over how to implement this.

```
<Tooltip title='Disabled' aria-label='disabled button'>
  <>
    <RequiredImportedButton title={this._getTitleMessage()} />
  </>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: why is this not an accepted answer? works fine

Comment: Be aware that (at least in some cases) fragment also prevents rendering the MUI tooltip. :-/

Answer (score 2):

You can choose another name for the propery and pass it to the `title`'s property of the button in the `RequiredImportedButton` component :

```
<Tooltip title='Disabled' aria-label='disabled button'>
  <RequiredImportedButton bTitle={this._getTitleMessage()} />
</Tooltip>

// RequiredImportedButton.js
function RequiredImportedButton(props) {
 const { bTitle} = props;

 ...

 return (<button title={bTitle}>My button</button>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DIV works fine but sometimes we may experience some design issues, so better wrap up in fragmentation tag, for example <>{props.children}</>

Comment: Please could you elaborate, I couldn't see the link between your answer and the question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Be aware that (at least in some cases) fragment also prevents rendering the MUI tooltip. :-/

Answer (score 0):

`RequiredImportedButton` probably sets the HTML `title` attribute. However, it should not do so if it's not for tooltip purposes. See [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/title):

> The HTMLElement.title property represents the title of the element: the text usually displayed in a 'tooltip' popup when the mouse is over the node.

The proper fix would be to prevent `RequiredImportedButton` from setting `title` attributes. If it's from a third-party, you can report a bug.

Some other answers suggest wrapping the child with either fragments or `<div>`. But they may break something: My experiments showed that wrapping with `fragments` would stop the tooltip from appearing and wrapping with `<div>` may potentially break styling.